# detect cancel of drop event using Dropzone js

Tags: drag-and-drop, event-handling, dropzone.js

I am using Dropzone js for file uploads. This works fine for all events but i do not know how to detect an event when user starts dragging a file but does not drop it over to the dropzone (or let's say he decides to cancel the drop operation)

JSP

```
<div class="FilesDropzone dz-clickable" id="mydropzone" style="width:97%;height:50px;"><span>Drop files here!</span>//area for further processing</div>
```

Javascript

```
var myFilesDropzone = new Dropzone("div#mydropzone", { url:addedFilesResourceURL});

myFilesDropzone .on("dragover", function(event){
       var dropzoneFilesHolder = document.getElementById('mydropzone');
       dropzoneFilesHolder.setAttribute('style', 'height:150px;border:3px dashed #2AAAE6;');
});

myFilesDropzone .on("drop", function(event){
    //display the dropped file  });
```

Currently a blue border area is displayed that shows users where to drop the file. So if user decides to cancel drop i want to hide that area. But i do not know which event exactly is it.

I tried with dragleave but figure out that it was not the correct event. Any ideas?

Comment: seems i might have mistaken here, I again tried out with adding dragleave event to the dropzone instance and clear the dropzone area . It is working now. But if you have any other ideas , do let me know.

Comment: Dragleave is the way...